# Points in an affine scheme over an algebraically closed field, and over an extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $K/k$ an extension field, and $A$ an affine $k$-algebra, i.e.,a quotient of a polynomial ring $k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ over $k$ by an ideal.  Suppose that there exist two different (unital) $K$-algebra homomorphisms $A \otimes_k K \to K$.  Do there necessarily exist two different (unital) $k$-algebra homomorphisms $A \to k$?

(The original post sloppily asked about the existence of *one* unital $k$-algebra homomorphism, which, as pointed out by @Sasha in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538625/points-in-an-affine-scheme-over-an-algebraically-closed-field-and-over-an-exten#comment9541751_4538625), follows just from the affine-ness of $A$.)

Comment: Hint: Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @Sasha, [right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538625/points-in-an-affine-scheme-over-an-algebraically-closed-field-and-over-an-exten#comment9541751_4538625), thanks!  That completely answers the original question … which I realised after gathering my wits wasn't what I meant.  I actually meant to ask whether the existence of two different homomorphisms over $K$ implied the existence of two different homorphisms over $k$, and have edited accordingly.

Comment: I think the Nullstellensatz remains relevant. It seems to me that if there is only one $k$-homomorphism $A \to k$ that is a severe restriction on what $A$ can be, and you should be able to deduce that there is also only one $K$-homomorphism $A \otimes_k K \to K$.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I [agree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538625/points-in-an-affine-scheme-over-an-algebraically-closed-field-and-over-an-exten#comment9541785_4538625) that *someone* should be able to deduce it.  But I don't yet know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the classical Nullstellensatz, if $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $A$ is a $k$-algebra of finite type such that there is only one $k$-homomorphism $A \to k$, then the kernel of that homomorphism is the nilradical of $A$.
Put it another way, $A$ must be generated (as a $k$-algebra) by nilpotent elements.
Therefore $A \otimes_k K$ is generated (as a $K$-algebra) by nilpotent elements.
In particular, its nilradical is a maximal ideal.
But any $K$-algebra homomorphism $A \otimes_k K \to K$ must annihilate nilpotent elements – put it another way, its kernel must contain the nilradical – so there is only one $K$-algebra homomorphism $A \otimes_k K \to K$, as claimed.